# Plural table names with Entity Frameworks Model First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm giving EF Model first a go. I'm using EF 4.1

Pretty much followed [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685494.aspx)

I've set PluraliseNewObjects to False on the Model and also in Options->Database Tools ->O/R Designer set Pluralization of names to false.

Neither have any effect - when I generate a new schema from the model the table names are always pluralised - is it possible to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I've found one way to achieve what I want - but it's a pretty daft route.

1. Generated db with the plural names (interesting that it only pluralised the tables mapping to types - not the auto-generated linking tables for many to many joins).
2. Manually renamed the tables in the database
3. Deleted Model from the project and recreated based on existing database schema (the one I've just renamed).
4. Model is now correctly mapped to singularly names tables.

I'll wait and see if anyone comes up with a more sensible way of achieving this....

Answer (score 0):

The names of the tables in the generated DDL seem to match the "Entity Set Name" values (different than the "Entity Name"). If you singularize the Entity Set Names, the table names in the DDL are singularized as well.

This will have the possibly undesired effect of singularizing the EntitySet property names in your code, though. Instead of:

```
myDatabase
.Products
.Where...
.Select...
```

your code will look like:

```
myDatabase
.Product
.Where...
.Select...
```

may or may not be an issue